# Why is Mono 3.x available specifically for OpenSuse and not other Linux (like Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, opensuse, mono

The Mono download page has a download for OpenSuse but not any other version of Linux. Why is that, is OpenSuse better suited for Mono for some reason than say Ubuntu?

We're developing on Macs using 3.2.5 and currently deploying to an Ubuntu (12.04) server using Mono 2.10. And notice some differences, especially artifacts in ServiceStack's razor engine but otherwise mostly ok. I tried installing 3.2.4 the long way around however the site just cashes on Ubuntu so had to roll that back to 2.10.

I now need to rebuild the server anyway and would like to know if OpenSuse is the better image for us to use this time...?

Comment: Mono 3.2.3 is in the portage tree for Gentoo, but masked as unstable.

Comment: I followed the process here to install it from latest. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13365158/installing-mono-3-x-3-0-x-and-or-3-2-x/13424880#13424880 (release 3.2.5 works fine on OS X but seems to crash in places on Ubuntu where latest doesn't)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the page at http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html, it seems like they used to have downloads for other distros for 2.10.x, under "Other", however it is stated that they are supported by their own communities. My guess would be that the third parties packaging Mono 2.10.x for Ubuntu and Debian have not submitted the packages to Mono.

Also, Mono was formerly developed by Novell which bought the SUSE brands and trademarks, which is what OpenSUSE is based on, and is possibly why Mono supports SUSE in particular.